# AWS Codebuild and codedeploy environment with jenkins and appsec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Environment using ECS tasks with CodeBuild and CodeDeploy(blue/green) integrates with jenkins. I added an appspec.yml file in the root of my repository code with all the configuration such as task definition arn and the container name and port. But when i trigger build from jenkins, I got an error saying

```
/appspec.DgpECS-jenkins-cluster-jen1.yml file does not exist.
```

[This ths snapshot of error  <----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l3Lq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is the deployment group name present in your `appsec` file name? If not, try to append that deployment group name because the error message is telling you that the file is missing.

In Jenkin [doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/codedeploy/), it says:

> The appspec file should be named "appspec.DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME.yml" and must be present in the jenkins project workspace.

Comment: yeah i already renamed my file as above but still getting the same error. This is the name of file 'appspec.DgpECS-jenkins-cluster-jen1.yml'